# Invoke() in SignalR. How to get data out?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

```
coreHubProxy.Invoke("QueryExchangeState", marketName).ContinueWith(task1 =>{});
```

When I run this code and debug it, I am able to see the result in task1.Result. However, I cannot get the result out as there is no task1.Task.

I am subscribed to the IHubProxy On method but updateExchangeState does not show there. It only appear in this task1.Result.

Answer (score 0):

Just `await` the call:

```
var result = await coreHubProxy.Invoke("QueryExchangeState", marketName);
```